# AWR Report Oracle Elapsed times

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am trying to use my own sql to query the db to get the same information the AWR report shows in "SQL ordered by Elapsed Time (Global)", specifically the SQL ID and the Elapsed (s).

So far I have this **query** :

```
SELECT SQL_ID, SUM (ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA)/1000000 Elapsed_Time_DELTA
FROM dba_hist_sqlstat
WHERE snap_id between 9185 and 9187
GROUP BY SQL_ID
ORDER by Elapsed_Time_DELTA Desc
```

The query above matches some of the elapsed times of the sql's but not others and I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.

- I notice that the ones which do not match span multiple snap_ids.

Answer (score 0):

Nm, realised when snap_id for my query should be +1 for the lower snap_id when compared to AWR. ie.

AWR 900-902
CustomQ 901-902